# aspectJ for normal web app without spring

Tags: rest, aop, aspectj

Hi can anyone please tell me how to add aop on normal jersey rest service or any web application without spring.
I have tried it with this link http://ganeshghag.blogspot.in/2012/10/demystifying-aop-getting-started-with.html but it didn't work. In this case i have added aop.xml in META-INF. But still it is not detecting the class which i have added with @Aspect annotation. Please can anyone help me out.
I am working in InteliJ idea and my code sample as follows.

```
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
```

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;

@Aspect
public class MySimpleLoggerAspect {

```
@Around("execution(* com.koderzlab.lawman.services.*.*(..))")
public Object myTrace(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("myTrace:before call "
            + joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getName()
            + "." + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());

    Object retVal = "it is an aspectJ sample";
    return retVal;
}
```

}

And my aop.xml is as follows

```
<aspectj>
<aspects>
    <aspect name="com.koderzlab.lawman.aop.MySimpleLoggerAspect"/>
</aspects>
```

I have added aop.xml in artifact as follows WEB-INF/META-INF/aop.xml
but aspect class is not executing before going to service

Comment: Your question is unclear because you do not provide enough information to make the problem at hand reproduceable. Just saying "I want to use AOP and it does not work" is not a particularly smart way to ask a question, especially if you expect a comprehensive answer. Please either update your question or delete it altogether.

Comment: @kriegaex Can you please help me to achieve aop in jersey rest service without spring. I don't know how to configure weaving feature in the application.

Comment: No, I cannot, see my previous comment. I need a reproduceable example.

Answer (score 0):

the folder META-INF is not child of WEB-INF, but they are at same level.